# Do hydrophobic materials keep bacteria away from open after surgery wounds?

Tags: infection, swimming, incision

I recently had an operation in the perianal area leaving me with a seton stitch (open wound) indefinitely. I was told to avoid the sea due to potential infection. I am wondering whether using hydrophobic material swimwear reduces the chances of bacteria in water coming in contact with the incision.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think hydrophobic swimwear keeps water away from your body. It's merely material that repels water and dries very quickly. Water would still flow freely through the leg openings. If you want truly waterproof swimwear, you could investigate dry suits made for scuba diving. Unfortunately, they're quite expensive and not comfortable at all in warm weather.

Comment: I have been having a look a that - I am wondering if you can get a dry suit 'shorts' rather than the entire suit. Doesn't look promising..